# split option with delimiter | into n-options in php

Tags: php

I have a dropdown menu that gets populated by data retrieved from the db. it looks like this:
[image]

How can I split the options like `GPOS RETAIL|INVENTORY STANDARD` into separate options `GPOS RETAIL` and `INVENTORY STANDARD`. Also, how can I remove the repetitive options? I already have `DISTINCT` in my query but I guess the pipeline `|` affects this.

I've been tried the ff but I couldn't seem to get the logic I need to  do what I need it to do

PHP:

```
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT c.c_id, c.client_name, a.product
    FROM client_list c
    INNER JOIN activities a
    ON c.client_name = a.client
    WHERE c.c_id = '".$_POST['client']."' AND a.product IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY c.c_id";
$res = mysql_query($qry);

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    echo '<option value="">SELECT SOFTWARE / HARDWARE</option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[2].'">'.$row[2].'</option>';
    }
} 
else {
    echo '<option value="">No Record</option>';
}
```

One of what I've tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['client'])) {  
            $qry = "SELECT DISTINCT c.c_id, c.client_name, a.software_hardware
                FROM client_list c
                INNER JOIN activities a
                ON c.client_name = a.client
                WHERE a.software_hardware IS NOT NULL AND c.c_id = '".$_POST['client']."'
                ORDER BY a.`software_hardware`";
            $res = mysql_query($qry);

            if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
                echo '<option value="">SELECT SOFTWARE / HARDWARE</option>';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                    $list = "";
                    $arr = explode("|", $row[2]);
                    if (!empty($arr)){
                        for($i = 0; $i<=$ctr; $i++) {           
                           $list .= "<option value='$arr[$i]'>$arr[$i]</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo $list;
                    // echo '<option value="'.$row[2].'">'.$row[2].'</option>';
                }
            } 
            else {
                echo '<option value="">No Record</option>';
            }
        }
```

I don't know where to go from here

Comment: First of all: DO NOT USE the mysql_* functions anymore! They 've been deprecated in PHP5.6 and removed in PHP7. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or the [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions. After all your SQL syntax is horrendous open for sql injection. You should regard prepared statements for security reasons. To answer your question: [PHP explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will solve your problem and have a special look at your foor loop. There 's an error.

Comment: @Marcel thank you for that I am aware of the deprecated issue it's just that the company I'm in still uses it :/ I realized using the explode after I posted but what I've done so far still lacks something (see edit)

Comment: Have a look at @Fenix Lam 's answer. Your for loop accesses the wrong variable. Instead of `$ctr` use `$arr`. I do not know what to say to companies that use techniques that are already obsolete today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
$items = [];

//get all items from database and explode the concat values.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $items = array_merge($items, explode('|', $row[2]));
}

//get only the distinct items.
$items = array_unique($items);

//remove the emtpy items.
$items = array_filter($items);

//initialize the list.
$list = '<option value="">SELECT SOFTWARE / HARDWARE</option>';

//create the list of unique items.
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $list .= '<option value="'.$item.'">'.$item.'</option>';
}
```

**Explanation:**

- You can remove all duplicates by using [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). The pipes (`|`) are removed by using the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function on the `while` loop.
- You can remove all empty items by using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) (without callback).

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/YWdKFU

Answer (score 3):

You can use explode and foreach in PHP. You need some additional check, so you don't get empty lines. It's something similar like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    echo '<option value="">SELECT SOFTWARE / HARDWARE</option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $names = explode("|",$row[2]);
        foreach ( $names as $name ) {
           if ( $name != "" ) {
             echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the explode, which makes an array from the name string with the "|" dividers. After it you go through each element of the array, and if it's not empty, you add it as an option. Please not I've changed the reference of the rows to "$name".

Comment: hi! i realized using explode late. I've update my code but something's still lacking about it. I'll give this a try thank you!\

Comment: this did the trick! thank you! additional question, how can i remove the repetitive GPOS parts?

Comment: That depends on the way you want to do it. Personally, I would alter the table or the SQL query somehow to work in a sane way, but I'm blind. In PHP, you could save all the already printed strings to an array, and check with in_array($needle,$haystack), if it's been already printed, and refrain from printing in case it had been.

Comment: substr($name,5,strlen($name))

Answer (score 2):

```
 for($i = 0; $i<=$ctr; $i++) {
   ...
 }
```

should be

```
for($i = 0, $length = count($arr); $i < $length; $i++) {
```

that's all

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because Fenix saw, that the for loop accessed the wrong variable.

Comment: @marcel, I just tried it and it wasn't displaying the options

Comment: True. You should recognize the length of the array: `for ($i = 0, $length = count($arr); $i < $length; $i++ ) {}`. In your code the `$ctr` variable is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a little hint, that you shouldn 't use the mysql_* functions anymore. I know, that you said, that your company is using an outdated php version. But ... u know, that you 're working twice and they will pay a lot more money for development and so on.

Your for loop is the problem. You can solve unique values there and the `$ctr` variable you are using in your for loop was never defined.

```
$arr = $arr = explode("|", $row[2]);
$arr = array_unique($arr);
for ($i = 0, $length = count($arr); $i < $length; $i++) {
    ...
}
```

The [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function will sort out duplicate values in your array. After that the for loop iterates through the unique values of your array.

After all you should think about normalizing your database structure. It is not recommended saving values like "value1|value2|value3". Think about an one to many or a many to many structure. This will make life much more easier.